# Operators in the Hilbert space of single mode light

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators

Is it possible to express an arbitrary operator $\hat{O}$ in a signal mode Hilbert space as a function of creation and annihilation operators?  i.e.

$\hat{o}=f(a^\dagger,a)$

In particular, is there a function  $f(a^\dagger,a)=|0\rangle\langle 0|$, being the projector onto vacuum state?

Comment: As long as there is no information missing in one representation it should be possible, but may not be very practical.  These operators are natural for describing the harmonic oscillator, or fields that obey a second order wave equation.  What would you expect to get by expanding the states of a Hydrogen atom in a SHO basis?  Or the Hamiltonian in terms of a, and a-dagger?

Comment: $|0\rangle \langle 0| =\int_{-\pi}^{+\pi}\frac{d\lambda}{2\pi} e^{i\lambda a^\dagger a} $?

Comment: It is a math problem. For $N=a^\dagger a$, consider $f(N)= (1-N)(\frac{2-N}{2})(\frac{3-N}{3})...$.